# Spatio temporal 2D-CNN-LSTM

Tags: time-series, conv-neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

train input shape : (13974, 100, 6, 5) 
train output shape : (13974, 1, 6, 5) 
test input shape : (3494, 100, 6, 5) 
test output shape : (3494, 1, 6, 5)

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), 
padding='same'), 
input_shape=(100, 6, 5,1)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Activation('relu')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(32, (3, 3))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Activation('relu')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.25)))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(512)))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(35, name="first_dense_flow" )))

model.add(LSTM(20, return_sequences=True, name="lstm_layer_flow"));    
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(101), name=" time_distr_dense_one_ flow ")) 

model.add(GlobalAveragePooling1D(name="global_avg_flow"))
model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])    model.fit(train_input,train_output,epochs=50,batch_size=60)
```

I am trying to build a CNN-LSTM model capable of detecting the future. Input is 13974 sequence, each sequence consists of 100 time stamps, each containing 6 locations and 5 features (variables)  and so the input is (13974,100,6,5) and the output is (13974,1,6,5).

How I can change my model so that the spatio temporal prediction can be done